# Is there any way to count the page number of docx, ppt or any file using Flutter(if not then can I do that using any other programming language)

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

Is there any way to count the page number of docx, ppt or any file using Flutter (if not then can I do that  using any other programming language)

Comment: Well you could study the [PPT specification](https://msopenspecs.azureedge.net/files/MS-PPT/%5bMS-PPT%5d-210422.pdf). DOCX is easier because it's actually a ZIP file containg XML files. If you're asking for a library which can handle all those formats at once then I think there is none. But there is [pdfbox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/) for PDF files for example.